# i have a problem building a databases in d-bever using sql-lite

Tags: database, sqlite, dbeaver

when I try to run my code the program keeps giving me syntax errors, but I can't understand why
CREATE TABLE School (
ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
Name TEXT NOT NULL,

);
CREATE TABLE events (
ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
details TEXT NOT NULL,
start_data TEXT NOT NULL,
end_data  TEXT NOT NULL,
title TEXT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_School_ID REFERENCES School(ID)

);

CREATE TABLE CALENDAR (
ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
title TEXT NOT NULL,
details TEXT NOT NULL,
start_data TEXT NOT NULL,
end_data  TEXT NOT NULL,
subject INTEGER NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_School_ID REFERENCES School(ID)

);

CREATE TABLE GRADES (
ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
title TEXT NOT NULL,
coefficent REAL NOT NULL,
value REAL NOT NULL,
date_time TEXT NOT NULL,
Subject INTEGER NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_School_ID REFERENCES School(ID)

);
''''

can you please help me find the mistake thank

Comment: Extra comma before `)` in the first statement. The rest have mistakes in the foreign key, because you need to define which column is the foreign key before `REFERENCES`. See examples: https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

Comment: i don't understand how to define it